# ¿Como puedo cambiar el tipo de dato de un csv de String a Double en PySpark?

Tags: csv, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark

Tengo un csv donde el tipo de dato de todas las columnas es String y quiero convertirlas a Double. El csv lo cargo en un DataFrame de Saprk utilizado PySpark. Yo se que con withColumn puedo cambiar el tipo de dato de una columna, pero cómo lo uso para cambiar el de todas las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta a mi pregunta. En el siguiente código dfX es un *CSV* conde todas sus columnas tienen tipo de dato *Double* y se cambián a *String*.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

dfX_String = dfX.select(
  [dfX[c].cast(StringType())
   .alias(c) for c in dfX.columns]
)
dfX_String.printSchema()
```

Este ejemplo de código hace la conversión a la inversa de como lo había preguntado. Es decir de *Double* a *String*, pero para hacerlo de *String* a *Double* basta con importar *DoubleType* para poder hacer el *cast* a *DoubleType* y que dfX sea un *CSV*  donde todas sus columnas sean de tipo *String*.